# Uploading images in p5 to create an animation and export it as video

Tags: javascript, animation, video, 3d, p5.js

I am trying to load a set of images, then for each image individually create an animation and then export this animation. The animation is just a rotating cube with the image on one side. At the moment i can upload the images in a batch but then i get and erro : `"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'gifProperties')"` which seems to be linked to the `texture()` command

I did the following for the moment:
To upload the files i can't really make a loop it seems since they don't have all the same name, i can't find a way to take all the images contained in a file without specifying the filename of each image. thus I did the following:

```js
let plate;
let invisible_sides;
let invisible_up_down;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(800, 800, WEBGL);
    textSize(18);
    text("Select the images", 20, 20);
    inputbtn = createFileInput(FileSimple,"true");
    inputbtn.position(30, 40);
    //then i need additional elements: 
    invisible_sides = createGraphics(400,400); 
    invisible_up_down= createGraphics(400,400);  
    BOX_WIDTH = 400;
    BOX_HEIGHT = 400;
    BOX_DEPTH = 400;
}
```

The invisible variables above are just made to fill in some sides of the cube with invisible textures.

Then I need to convert the file data to an image, to do so i called the FileSimple function in my setup -- createFileInput :

```
function FileSimple(file){

if (file.type == 'image'){

    plate = createImg(file.data, '' )

}else{

    img = null;

} }
```

Then i found on another Stack Overflow question this answer for a rotating cube animation with different textures on the different sides: (I am sorry i can't find the feed anymore)

```
 function drawFaceBox(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth,
 front, top, right, bottom, left, back) {
   angleMode(DEGREES); 
   let w = boxWidth * SCALE_FACTOR;
   let h = boxHeight * SCALE_FACTOR;
   let d = boxDepth * SCALE_FACTOR;

   // Center the box.
   translate(-w / 2, -h / 2);

    texture(front);
    quad(0, 0, w, 0, w, h, 0, h);

    push();
    texture(left);
    translate(0, 0, -d);
    rotateY(-90);
    quad(0, 0, d, 0, d, h, 0, h);

    pop();
    push();
    texture(top);
    translate(0, 0, -d);
    rotateX(90);
    quad(0, 0, w, 0, w, d, 0, d);

    pop();
    push();
    texture(right);
    translate(w, 0, 0);
    rotateY(90);
    quad(0, 0, d, 0, d, h, 0, h);

    pop();
    push();
    texture(bottom);
    translate(0, h, 0);
    rotateX(-90);
    quad(0, 0, w, 0, w, d, 0, d);

    pop();
    push();
    texture(back);
    rotateY(180);
    translate(-w, 0, d);
    quad(0, 0, w, 0, w, h, 0, h);
  }
```

here we seem to have the problem about the texture action.

Finally i would like to display the animation thus I runned the draw function as such:

```
function draw(){
 background(255);

 drawFaceBox(BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT, BOX_DEPTH,
 plate, invisible_up_down, invisible_sides, invisible_up_down, invisible_sides, 
 plate);   }
```

for the exporting part of the project, i thought about using this tutorial : https://stubborncode.com/posts/how-to-export-images-and-animations-from-p5-js/

thank you very much for any help you can give

Comment: It is better if you ask one question a a time 1. The issue with uploading an image and using at as a texture. 2. recording a sketch as a video.

Comment: Yes sorry, at first the export part wasn't really a question although i will probably to make a new question about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your call to `texture()` is that it's parameter *must not* be null or undefined. You can resolve this by defaulting to your blank texture when `plate` has not yet been defined:

```js
const SCALE_FACTOR = 0.5;

let arial;
let plate;
let blank;

function preload() {
  arial = loadFont('https://www.paulwheeler.us/files/Arial.otf');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
  textFont(arial);
  textSize(18);
  text("Select the images", 20, 20);
  inputbtn = createFileInput(FileSimple, "true");
  inputbtn.position(30, 40);
  //then i need additional elements:
  blank = createGraphics(400, 400);
  BOX_WIDTH = 400;
  BOX_HEIGHT = 400;
  BOX_DEPTH = 400;
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  
  orbitControl(1, 1, 0.1);

  drawFaceBox(
    BOX_WIDTH,
    BOX_HEIGHT,
    BOX_DEPTH,
    // Don't pass null or undefined here because texture() will fail
    plate || blank,
    blank,
    blank,
    blank,
    blank,
    plate || blank
  );
}

function FileSimple(file) {
  if (file.type == "image") {
    plate = createImg(file.data, "");
  }
}

function drawFaceBox(
  boxWidth,
  boxHeight,
  boxDepth,
  front,
  top,
  right,
  bottom,
  left,
  back
) {
  angleMode(DEGREES);
  let w = boxWidth * SCALE_FACTOR;
  let h = boxHeight * SCALE_FACTOR;
  let d = boxDepth * SCALE_FACTOR;

  // Center the box.
  translate(-w / 2, -h / 2);

  texture(front);
  quad(0, 0, w, 0, w, h, 0, h);

  push();
  texture(left);
  translate(0, 0, -d);
  rotateY(-90);
  quad(0, 0, d, 0, d, h, 0, h);

  pop();
  push();
  texture(top);
  translate(0, 0, -d);
  rotateX(90);
  quad(0, 0, w, 0, w, d, 0, d);

  pop();
  push();
  texture(right);
  translate(w, 0, 0);
  rotateY(90);
  quad(0, 0, d, 0, d, h, 0, h);

  pop();
  push();
  texture(bottom);
  translate(0, h, 0);
  rotateX(-90);
  quad(0, 0, w, 0, w, d, 0, d);

  pop();
  push();
  texture(back);
  rotateY(180);
  translate(-w, 0, d);
  quad(0, 0, w, 0, w, h, 0, h);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much this seems to do the trick, but i was wondering why do i have the diagonals of my quad ? i wanted only the sides and i can't seem to find out why. Also I don't understand why it is also displaying the image I imported outside the canvas. Thank you

Comment: So i have used noStroke(); to take out the diagonals and all the vertex of my cube, it worked out but i still don't understand why i had the diagonals, and the second part of my question still holds, why is it also displaying the image i imported underneath ?